# BindingSource Filter by date and string

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

I have a date query as follow:

```
ShipD: IIf(RecQry].[Gate]="GN", [RecQry].[SDATEE], "")
```

Tried this one as well:

```
ShipD: IIf(RecQry].[Gate]="GN", CDate([RecQry].[SDATEE]), "")
```

Now, when I do the binding source filter with the following code, it gives me error.

```
dDate = String.Format("[" & ShipDStr & "] >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# and 
[" & ShipDStr & "] <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", StartDate.Text, EndDate.Text)
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot perform '>=' operation on System.String and System.DateTime

I tried removing the hash sign from the filter, still get the error except this time it was

> Additional information: Cannot perform '>=' operation on System.String = and System.Double

Tried using the following code, I still get an error:

```
dDate = "[" & ShipDStr & "] >= #{" & StartDate.Text & ":M/dd/yyyy}# and [" &
ShipDStr & "] <= #{" & EndDate.Text & ":M/dd/yyyy}#"
```

> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

The output will be displayed on the datagridview. I can hide it temporarily, but when I tried to export it, those hidden value will eventually show up. 
Could anyone provide some recommendation to solve this?

Comment: You should add more code to show how these are used.  I cant tell what you are trying to tell us with `ShipD: ...` is that a label?  It would also help us understand what it is to `do the binding source filter`

Comment: @Plutonix The [tag:ShipD] is part of the access query. I'm trying to filter the query for a report using the binding source with the provided code. There is nothing else to show other than the one that I already provided. The [tag:ShipDStr] is string containing the name of the query, which is the [tag:ShipD] in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
ShipD: IIf(RecQry].[Gate]="GN", [RecQry].[SDATEE])
```

Removing the false value from the query should fix it.